# Image transformation and input image

Tags: image, transformation, bufferedimage

If I want to do the image transformation like moving horizontally or vertically, do i need to first write the command like reading from my C drive to input the image into java?

Comment: Hi So... you might want to read some tutorials if your asking this basic question. Once you decided in which language you're goiing to code and actually do code and get errors... then you may consider asking again on SO for help.Try python (conda install), opencv (cv2) and enjoy the ride.

Comment: If you want to read a `BufferedImage` in Java, `ImageIO` is the API you are looking for. It has methods for reading and writing images, supports multiple formats via plug-ins, etc. Also, I highly recommend reading [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) from the Java 2D tutorial.